# Does a heat mat need current protection?

Tags: power-supply, heat, heat-protection

Would any sort of extra circuitry be needed for connecting a heat mat into a power supply?

The mat says it draws 4.1A and the power supply can provide 6A, both working at 12V. Will it work as is, or will the mat cook itself like an LED and need some form of current limiting tool?

[The mat is this one](https://rover.ebay.com/rover/0/0/0?mpre=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ebay.com.au%2Fulk%2Fitm%2F273112728093)

[The power supply is this one](https://rover.ebay.com/rover/0/0/0?mpre=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ebay.com.au%2Fulk%2Fitm%2F162567927732)

Comment: YES you need a controller (could be the 3D printer controller) and a power switch. How else to set the setpoint? This should be migrated to the 3D printing SE.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany it’s posted here because I don’t really care about the print aspect, just tried to see that if I hooked everything up it would work, and everyone here is good at knowing if things will work 

Comment: I suspect they might know more about how to wire the power controller to the MCU and update your firmware to enable that functionality over there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The heating mat is just a large resistor. For 12V at 50W that would be a resistance of 2.88 Ohm.

If you can supply 6 Amp and it only needs 4.1 then you are fine.

It will work fine as is. Adding a switch would be a good idea in case you want to let the printer control the heat itself (in conjunction with a temp sensor)

There is danger of overheating due to insufficient cooling (or being too well isolated) however that is independent of the pad's performance.

Comment: ..... off-topic?

Comment: I wasn't finished, a stray tab press caused me to submit too soon

Comment: I was only messing around!

Comment: Great, cheers. So the pad knows when to say no to too much current and everything should be sweet?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know enough about 3-D printing. but you probably want to keep the temperature constant. If only to have the same result in summer as in winter or when making a small versus big object.  So I think it is a good idea to add a regulator system.

For temperatures you can use a simple on/off regulator, no need to mess with DC regulation or PWM systems.

You might ask at the 3d stack exchange: https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Definitely a good point with temp regulation, maybe I’ll buy a regulator and a little thermo screen so I can what’s happening. I posted here because everyone can spot catastrophes a mile off.

Answer (score 1):

1. The mat is equipped with a temperature sensor. An NTC 100K with profile 3950. You can buy a thermostat for this. Beware of relay contact ratings at DC, I'd suggest a solid state solution (an SSR or mosfet) to switch the mat.
2. You supply is 72 Watts, which is theoretically* enough. Check if you supply is able to do 100% of the rated power for long periods of time, and check if it has overload protection. This can prevent failure of the supply.
3. Yes, it will also stay at a stable temperature. Whatever the ambient conditions, assuming the conditions are within system limits*.

**eg: no blazing hurricane winds cooling the plate*